# Do all electrons in an element move at the same speed and have the same momentum angular vs non-angular momentum?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrons

Do electrons' speed, energy, angular momentum increase when they are in the p, d, and f rather than in the s orbital? Do all electrons in a specific orbital, say for example, the f orbital all have the same speed, energy, angular momentum? Do electrons in the f orbital have higher angular momentum as a result of their distance from the radius or because of their higher speed, energy, or something else?

Comment: Electrons are not tiny little moons in orbit about the nucleus. One could say the wave function 'is' an electron. There is an angular momentum quantum number associated with each wave function, however.

Comment: In simple words, we can say almost nothing about properties of an individual electron in a many electron system